# How do I use the axis as an anchor for horizontal alignment?

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, axis

[image]

I want these two distances to be equal, when I add the y label it "pushes" the axis for the right. Is there any way to anchor the axis in tikz/pgf?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
        \begin{axis}[
        ylabel = {something},
        ]
        \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not repost the same question. If you need to attract attention, you can do it with bounties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={something},
]
\addplot{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[dashed] (current page.north) -- (current page.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Centered graph on page]